# Is there a helper in Visual Studio that finds the needed Module for a particular keyword?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, module, ide, intellisense

Does the Visual Studio 2012 have a facility to locate needed modules based on a keyword?  I find myself spending a fair amount of time hunting down the correct module to reference with the "using" statement for various keywords.  For example, today I had to search the web to learn that I needed **System.ComponentModel** to use the **DisplayName** attribute (or any other attribute I'm guessing) with a class property.  In Java/Eclipse the IDE has a hot key that will attempt to locate the module for a keyword it is flagging as unresolved in the current context.  Is there a similar facility in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Just to check - are you viewing "DisplayName" as a keyword here? (It's not, as far as C# is concerned.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - What is the correct terminology for any text that appears in C# code that the IDE will attempt to resolve?

Comment: Well in this case it's an attribute name, and you need to know the reference to add. For other cases it would be a class name etc... (Note that it's both the namespace *and* assembly which is important here. "Module" isn't really a useful concept in the context of this question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I understand that.  I need a meta-term to describe any text that the IDE will attempt to resolve to a namespace, since that is what triggers the need to know the source module whose namespace contains the term.  How about term then instead of keyword?

Comment: list of `keywords` is part of C# specification (like `for` or `int`). You probably should use "class name"/"type name" in this particular context.

Answer (score 4):

A tool like [`Resharper`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (paid!) will make the job a lot easier. It has almost become the de-facto standard in C#/VB development with Visual Studio. Resharper can reference the assembly *and* add the `using` statements too.

With that said, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> after enter the class name ( in this case `DisplayName`) and it should suggest namespace. But for that, the assembly has to be referenced, and many a times, it might not be.

To reiterate, get Resharper, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a reference to the appropriate *assembly*, Visual Studio will offer to help you if you have the cursor in the troublesome name. For example, if you try to apply the attribute:

```
[DisplayName]
```

... if you put your text caret in `DisplayName` and press Ctrl-period, it should offer you the option of adding the appropriate `using` directive. (Or click in the little bar at the bottom left of the name, which should appear.)

I don't *believe* Visual Studio offers you the option of adding an assembly reference in order to find a missing type though.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Ctrl-period was the secret sauce I needed.  I think I need to find a list of top IDE facilities and review it.

Comment: @RobertOschler: If your text caret is in the `DisplayName`, it should show up - or use Ctrl+Period to bring it up explicitly.

Comment: That was the problem.  I expected the hover tool tip to show the module lookup facility.  It does on occasion (small tiny square icon like the rename icon), but most of the time I get a hover tool tip that just shows the error message.  Ctrl-period is much more reliable.

Comment: @RobertOschler note "already have a reference to the appropriate assembly" part of the answer - tooltip will not show up without it. Note that Resharper (see manojlds answer) will do broader search and offer to add references in the same case. (+1 to this and manojlds "try ReSharper" answers).